# Symfony2 + Doctrine: Retrieve information from 2 entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I use `Symfony2` and `FOSCommentBundle` and I have add a `comment` to a specific entity `App\MyBundle\Post`.

I want to retrieve all information concerning all the `App\MyBundle\Post` and all the specified `comment`, I mean if I have 2 comments for a post, I want it returns me into my row for example:

> P.*, 2 as nbComment

So I have try this code:

```
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery ('
           SELECT      P, COUNT(C.id) as nbComment
           FROM        AppMyBundle:Post P
           LEFT JOIN   AppMyBundle:Comment C ON C.id=CONCAT('post_',P.id)
           GROUP BY    P.id
           ORDER BY    P.dEvent DESC, P.dCreated DESC'
    );
```

But I have an error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 96 near 'Com ON C.id=CONCAT("post_",P.id)
>   WHERE': Error: Identification Variable Comment used in join path expression but was not defined before.

Please help me

Thanks Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you do a LEFT JOIN in DQL. See here in the [manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins).

Comment: All right I know that I can't do left join 'on' according the documentation, but I have no "physical" link beetween the post entity and Comment entity. The only link I have is : comment.id=CONCAT('post_',post.id)

Comment: Oh. I see. I think you really should have a physical link. Write an sql migration to a new table structure, you'll gain in speed an usability.

Comment: What do you mean? I have to have comment_id like CONCAT('mytable_',mytable.id) because I want to instantiate comment to several entities. So I don't know how I can do it...

Comment: If you want to link to several entities, I guess you'll have add a column for each entity in your comment table. I'm not sure this is the best solution, but I think it is better than what you have now. I think you should write another question just for this modelisation problem.